# SDL2 project gives undefined reference to `SDL_Init` even when SDL2_LIBRARIES is linked

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, cmake, sdl-2

I create CMake project which uses SDL2 by following [this tutorial](https://trenki2.github.io/blog/2017/06/02/using-sdl2-with-cmake/). However, I keep getting this error

```
usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp -o /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccbnY9S2.o: in function `main':
/home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp:32: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp:34: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm on Ubuntu and use VSCode with CMake.
Here is the structure of my project:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBGjY.png)

Here is my `main.cpp`:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize the SDL2 library\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Window",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          680, 480,
                                          0);

    if(!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Surface *window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    if(!window_surface)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get the surface from the window\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    SDL_Delay(5000);
}
```

And here is my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(Pong)


find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(Pong src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Pong ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

Note that I did install CMake (and Ninja, because I got errors involving Ninja, that were solved by installing it), G++ and SDL2 (the `libsdl2-dev` package) using `apt-get` beforehand.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Command line `usr/bin/g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main.cpp -o /home/myUsername/Documents/Coding/CPP/Pong/src/main` definitely misses linking with SDL2 library. You could try to add `message("SDL2_LIBRARIES: ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}")` at the end of your `CMakeLists.txt` and check that this variable is not empty.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It seems that the variable is not empty, because when I do it, it returns ```SDL2_LIBRARIES: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lSDL2```. Though it seems that strangely, SDL2main is not in there. I tried changing ```target_link_libraries(Pong ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})``` to ```target_link_libraries(Pong ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} SDL2main)``` but it didn't do anything.

Comment: OK, I see - the variable is not empty. There is another strange thing about the command line: It combines both **compiling** and **linking** into the **single command**. As far as I know, CMake splits compiling and linking into separate commands (that is, the first command gets `-c` flag and outputs into `.o` or `.cpp.o` file; the second command uses that file for link). Are you sure that given command line is generated by CMake? It could be that some VSCode extension transforms the command line. Have you tried to configure and build your project **standalone**, in the command line?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do have CMake Tools installed on VSCode, maybe that would help. Also, i tried going into the ```Pong/``` folder and running ```cmake build/``` then going into ```build/``` and running ```make``` and for some reason it worked perfectly, and i could run the executable. Strange....

Comment: Sorry, I am not expert with VSCode extensions, so I cannot suggest where to search further. But worked command line configuration/building clearly points to that extensions...

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yeah... I'll look into that...